# Need help on PowerShell column looping

Tags: shell, powershell

I have one requirement which should be done in windows PowerShell or command line. I need to split CSV file columns into `.txt` files.

`customer.csv`:

```
id,name
1,a
2,b
```

I need to split columns into text files (here rows and columns count are dynamic)

The output text files should be as follows:

`id.txt`:

```
1
2
```

`name.txt`:

```
a
b
```

I found the following script with the help of Google:

```
$a = Import-Csv "D:\Final\customer.csv"
$b =  $a[0] | Get-Member | select -Skip 1 |  ? { $_.membertype -eq 'noteproperty'} 
$b | % { $a | ft -Property $_.name | out-file "$($_.name).txt"  }
```

But the output text files are coming with column names, spaces & etc.. I am unable to customize the above code. Kindly provide any help and let me know if any one needs more information.

Thank you,

Satish Kumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is the use of `ft` (`Format-Table`) which **formats** data from the CSV file, thus the spaces.

The following PowerShell script is cleaner way to do it:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Final\customer.csv'
$columns = $csv | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty

foreach( $c in $columns )
{
    foreach( $line in $csv )
    {
        Add-Content -Path $( $c.Name + '.txt' ) -Value $line.$( $c.Name )
    }
}
```